# No module named 'ImageDraw'

Tags: python

I am trying to make a wordcloud in Python.

Ran this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import ImageDraw
img_grey = Image.new("L", (10, 15))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_grey)
```

and I am getting this error
No module named 'ImageDraw'

PS: i already installed pip in command prompt

Comment: Well, you imported Image from PIL but where do you think you are importing ImageDraw from?

Comment: from PIL itself?

Comment: I'm trying to guide you towards finding the answer yourself. What is different about how you import Image, which works, and ImageDraw, which doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

The below fixed my issues:

```
#import Image, ImageDraw, ImageChops
from PIL.Image import core as Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageChops
```

*<rant>*
Any sort of package dependency is a disaster waiting to happen. I am a victim of an older build-out process that now breaks because of updates to PIL. Aim to just source control the final full project source code **including any libraries** and avoid dynamic build dependencies or dependences on system wide packages! Pip, npm, your-favorite-package-manager as part of a build process is idiotic. *</rant>*

Answer (score 1):

Execute "pip install Pillow" or "pip install Pillow" in your python environment, then run again